# App to dial a number in nokia phone using C#

Tags: c#, mobile, mobile-phones

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dial mobile phone via C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785786/dial-mobile-phone-via-c-program)

I have nokia phone connected to the computer through USB. Now I want to create an application which can dial the number in this nokia phone. For that we have to use AT COMMANDS. But i dont know how to use that. But I can create code using C# to find Serial ports of the computer.
So how can I ceate the program using **C#**?

This link shows about the nokia AT Commands= http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/AT_Commands

```
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(port);

        }
```

Comment: You asked the same question a week ago, but for a Sony Ericsson phone…

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps to send AT commands to nokia mobile:

1. Configure and open the serial port using `using System.IO.Ports` class

   `Serialport.open()` and `Serialport.close()` API are available for doing the same.
2. Write the AT command to opened COM port in step 1.

   `Serialport.Writeline()` API can be used for same.

I'm writing sample code below to be more specific:

```
private SerialPort portConfig = new SerialPort();   
portConfig.PortName = COM4; // Configure port with other details as well

portConfig.Open(); //open the port

// send AT command to dial a number
portConfig.WriteLine("ATD" + mobileNumber + ";");
```

This is not tested code, its just a sample code. You need to do more reading on how to do serial port communication. Here is [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/11ecee43-a8ac-4d8f-98bc-fc8bb205176b) for serial port communication programming.

I dont have any such facility to test this. So, let me know once you test it.