# Dial mobile phone via C# program

Tags: c#

I m trying to Dial mobile phone via C# program. Below Show my Program. In this, When i Click my Dial Button it dial the number(Destination number) which i given in my program. But after one or two seconds it is disappeared & its not connect to the that destination number. Below Shows my C# code. Pls help me to solve this problem. Thank you.......

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM10";
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
            sp.DtrEnable = true;
            sp.RtsEnable = true;


            sp.Open();

            if (!sp.IsOpen)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Serial port is not opened");
                return;
            }

            sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.WriteLine("ATD=\"" + "Destination Number" + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);

        }
    }
}
```

Finally i found the solution. We should add the semi-colon to end of the destination number. then its worked.

```
sp.WriteLine("ATD=\"" + "Destination Number;" + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Finally i found the solution. We should add the ; to end of the destination number. then its worked.

Answer (score 1):

Increase your `BaudRate` to max and use this `AT` Command:

```
ATD = DestinationNumber;
```

This will not work with out `;` as the system will think you are taking a data call and not a voice call.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the decleration of the 'sp' outside the method, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort sp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sp = new SerialPort();           
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                sp.Close();
            }

            sp.PortName = "COM10";
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
            sp.DtrEnable = true;
            sp.RtsEnable = true;


            sp.Open();

            if (!sp.IsOpen)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Serial port is not opened");
                return;
            }

            sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
            sp.WriteLine("ATD=\"" + "Destination Number" + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working dialing cord it rings the phone 
Don't knows that how to get the voice input and out put from port I'm using huwavi E173 dongle.Here is my working cord C#

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
port.Open();
string t = port.ReadExisting();
Thread.Sleep(100);

string cmd = "ATD";
Thread.Sleep(100);
string phoneNumber = "071********";
Thread.Sleep(100);
port.WriteLine(cmd + phoneNumber + ";\r");

port.Close();
```